# How to test null or missing for enquos-type quosures

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

There's a quite subtle (and very confusing) distinction in rlang that... quosures are not quosure objects! In other terms:

- `quo()` and `enquo()` return a quosure
- `quos()` and `enquos()` return a quosure**S**, not a quosure (`is_quosure(enquos(...))` returns `FALSE`)

What is the equivalent of `quo_is_null()` and `quo_is_missing()` for quosures? In particular, I would like to test the `...` argument, captured by `enquos(...)`, is null/missing, how do I do that?

```r
library(rlang)
fo1 <- function(df, var1) {
  dot_vars <- rlang::enquo(var1)
  quo_is_missing(dot_vars)
}

fo2 <- function(df, ...) {
  dot_vars <- rlang::enquos(...)
  quo_is_missing(dot_vars)
}

fo1()
#> [1] TRUE
fo2()
#> `quo` must be a quosure
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `length(dot_vars)` to determine if it has a length of 0.

Comment: @g-grothendieck can you elaborate or add a detailed explanation to this answer. At present, it's too succinct in nature!

Comment: The length function returns the length of its argument. If the length is 0 the enquos object has no elements.